# Xdebug breaks Apache alias directives

Tags: apache, xampp, xdebug

I installed and configured [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). Here is my configuration:

```
[Zend]
;zend_extension_ts = "D:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll"
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts = "D:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\Optimizer"
;zend_optimizer.enable_loader = 0
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_optimizer.license_path =
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:

[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
;zend_extension_ts="D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
zend_extension_ts = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.4-5.2-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:\xampp\tmp"
```

I have also checked the **Xdebug** installation [according to this](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installation). It is working fine.
The problem is that my Apache alias directive is not working after **Xdebug** is installed. I have the following configuration in `D:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

```
Alias /example "D:\xampp\htdocs\example\html"
Alias /example2 "D:\xampp\htdocs\example2\html"
```

Before I installed **Xdebug**, they are working fine. I could browse `localhost/example` and `localhost/example2`. But after I have installed **Xdebug**, I could not browse them. They are redirecting to `www.localhost.com/example` and `www.localhost.om/example2`.
When I removed the Xdebug configuration, they are back to the running state.

I'm using XAMPP 1.6.7.

## [UPDATE]

I just noticed Xdebug (php_xdebug.dll) comes with XAMPP by default. However, when I used it, my localhost is completely gone.

```
zend_extension_ts="D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;zend_extension_ts = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.4-5.2-vc9.dll"
```